# Find and Replace of Elements of List in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, replace

I am having 3 big lists `L0`, `L1` and `L2` with 106756, 106588 and 100 words respectively.

`L0` and `L1` consisting the data tokenize into token of words, and `L2` consisting of the words that are common to both `L0` and `L1` lists.

Suppose that,

```
L1 = ['newnes', 'imprint', 'elsevier', 'corporate', 'drive', 'suite',
     'burlington', 'usa', 'linacre', 'jordan', 'hill', 'oxford', 'uk', 
     'elsevier', 'inc', 'right', 'reserved', 'exception', 'newness', 'uk', ...]

L2 = ['usa', 'uk', 'hill', 'drive', ... ]
```

As you can see in L1 list there is `repetition of the words` like `'newness'`, `'uk'`.

What I need is that, for every `discovered (found)` word in `L2`, like (say `'newness'`, `'uk'`), I need to replace it with its `modified injected form` like appending a `special character` either at the `start` or `end` `position` of that discovered word. 
Further, for all instances of the discovered word (in `L2`), should be replaced with the modified version of the same word in `L1`. For Example,

Suppose, the word `newness` occurred 100 times in `L1` list (say) and newness is a word also present in `L2`. Similarly, there are also 100 words in `L2` and that are also present in `L1`, with multiple frequencies.

Then, after transformation the list should look somewhat like this:

```
newness ------> $newness$

uk -----------> $uk$
```

...

How to achieve this in a list? Help please. I am also a new-bie to python. I am just curious to know whether there exist some command in python for achieving this? I don't know where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count things in list, python provides a dict-like Counter() class in its collections module: [Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which counts occurences in O(n) and provides them as dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter


L1 = ['newnes', 'imprint', 'elsevier', 'corporate', 'drive', 'suite',
     'burlington', 'usa', 'linacre', 'jordan', 'hill', 'oxford', 'uk', 
     'elsevier', 'inc', 'right', 'reserved', 'exception', 'newness', 'uk', ...]

L2 = ['usa', 'uk', 'hill', 'drive', ... ]


c = Counter(L1)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'elsevier': 2, 'uk': 2, 'newnes': 1, 'imprint': 1, 'corporate': 1, 
         'drive': 1, 'suite': 1, 'burlington': 1, 'usa': 1, 'linacre': 1, 
         'jordan': 1, 'hill': 1, 'oxford': 1, 'inc': 1, 'right': 1, 'reserved': 1,
         'exception': 1, 'newness': 1, Ellipsis: 1})
```

It provides a convenience method to get the result sorted as list of tuples `(key, count)` named [most_common()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) - if you use the first one, you get the most used word which you can use together with a list comprehension to modify your source list:

```
word,_ = c.most_common()[0]  # get word mos often used

# inplace modification of L1
L1[:] = [ x if x != word else "#"+word+"#" for x in L1] # use x if not the most used word
L2[:] = [ x if x != word else "#"+word+"#" for x in L2] # else pre-/append #

print(L1)
print(L2)
```

Output:

```
['newnes', 'imprint', '#elsevier#', 'corporate', 'drive', 'suite', 'burlington', 
 'usa', 'linacre', 'jordan', 'hill', 'oxford', 'uk', '#elsevier#', 'inc', 
 'right', 'reserved', 'exception', 'newness', 'uk', Ellipsis]

['usa', 'uk', 'hill', 'drive', Ellipsis]
```

The order of items in `Counter` relates to the order in the original list, you got multiple items wiht a count of 2 in `L1` - `elsevier` is the first of them, hence it is also the first when using `most_common()`

---

Edit 4 comment:

```
from collections import Counter

L1 = ['newnes', 'imprint', 'elsevier', 'corporate', 'drive', 'suite',
     'burlington', 'usa','imprint', 'linacre', 'jordan', 'hill', 'oxford', 'uk','uk', 
     'elsevier', 'inc', 'right', 'reserved','imprint', 'exception', 'imprint','newness', 'uk', "..."]

L2 = ['usa', 'uk', 'hill', 'drive', "..."]


c = Counter(L1) 


substs = "#*+~-:;=)(/&%$§!"
i = 0
for word,count in c.most_common():
    temp = substs[i]*count # use the i-th char as substitute, apply it count times
    L1[:] = [ x if x != word else temp+word+temp for x in L1] # use x if not the most used word
    L2[:] = [ x if x != word else temp+word+temp for x in L2] # else pre-/append #
    i += 1
    i = i % len(substs) # wrap around

print(L1)
print(L2)
```

Output:

```
['~newnes~', '####imprint####', '++elsevier++', '-corporate-', ':drive:', ';suite;', 
 '=burlington=', ')usa)', '####imprint####', '(linacre(', '/jordan/', '&hill&', 
 '%oxford%', '***uk***', '***uk***', '++elsevier++', '$inc$', '§right§', '!reserved!', 
 '####imprint####', '#exception#', '####imprint####', '*newness*', '***uk***', 
 '+...+']

[')usa)', '***uk***', '&hill&', ':drive:', '+...+']
```

Comment: The above code transform only the top word of List 1, having the highest frequency. How to incorporate the same in all the words of list irrespective of frequency? I mean how to transform both the words `elsevier` and `uk` of L1 in a single step?

Comment: @MishraSiba see edit. Not in a single step, but you can iterate over the Counter-results and apply any changes that you like to both lists. I use the `i-th` character and multiply it count times before pre-/postfixing, for all results of counter. This is not one step, its a look that modifies one list after the other, replacing one word, then the next. use a `print(L1)` inside the loop to see your data change forms.

Comment: Hello Patrick. How to do the same in time efficient manner. Suppose If I have large data. Injecting special character like word to #word# needs more time.

Comment: @M_S youmight need to ask a new question if it is a different problem - if you tried solving it with this answer, detail how/what did not work as you thought you needed it to work.